# Android Maven project on IntelliJ IDEA does not find R class

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to reference the R class on my code, which is an Android Maven Project created on IntelliJ IDEA 12, but the R class has not been found after compiling the entire Project.

Why? And how to solve this?

Comment: Please share a project to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved with the suggestion made by Eugene Kudelevsky on JetBrains forums:

> Coluld you please check following:
>
> Go to Project Structure | Modules | choose Android facet to open facet settings. Then open "Compiler" tab. Is "Run 'process-resources' Maven task before Make" selected? I did manage to reproduce the problem in such case only.

http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5474227#5474227